# Assigning a value to a variable randomly, but not working

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Im trying write JavaScript code which will generate a random number through a function then use that random number (between 1 and 6) to assign a value to the variable "background".

This is what I have:

```
function genBackground() {

var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);

assignBG(x);
alert("test alert");
}

function assignBG(x) {
if (x === 1){
var background=blue;}
else if (x === 2){
var background=green;}
else if (x === 3){
var background=red;}
else if (x === 4){
var background=purple;}
else if (x === 5){
var background=yellow;}
else if (x === 6){
var background=orange;}
}
```

The alert "test alert" doesn't show, but does if but before the line "assignBG(x);". Have I done this bit wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those "colors" defined previously in the code? Otherwise, you should write `color = "white"` and so on...

I'd also rewrite assignBG like this:

```
function genBackground() {

    var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);

    var color = generateBG(x);
    alert(color); // and do whatever you like with this color
}

function generateBG(x) {
    var colors = ["blue","green","red","purple","yellow","orange"];
    return colors[x];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by previously defined? This is the full code

Comment: I mean that `blue`, `green`, `purple` are variable names, not atoms or strings... There are no such global variables predefined in JS.

Comment: ive used your re-written version of function assignBG() and it works, thanks

Comment: I've rewritten it once again, so it doesn't use global variables (it is considered a bad practice). Also, did't this error show up in browser's developer console?